# How to create queue in rabbitmq from spring-boot with rabbitmq docker

Tags: docker, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I've lost an entire day to trying to get the spring-amqp example project up and running against a docker version of rabbitmq.  I'm just running the standard rabbitmq docker.  While I have no trouble connecting, I always get exceptions related to creating a queue, and I have tried every possible variant, at this point.

I've tried to just declare the queues in my configuration like the sample project.  I've tried explicitly configuring a RabbitAdmin.  I've tried explicitly configuring the whole autoconfigured mess.  I've created a new user in rabbitmq and explicitly assigned permissions.  I've tried just using queue names without actually declaring queue beans.  I've tried injecting queues and RabbitAdmin into other beans, just to force them to be created.

No matter what I attempt, I get the following errors:

```
2017-04-24 17:42:19.709  WARN 37360 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue:"incoming"
2017-04-24 17:42:19.715  WARN 37360 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Queue declaration failed; retries left=3

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):["incoming"]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:621) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:520) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1382) [spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:105) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:101) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:123) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:992) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:50) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:955) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:600) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue '"incoming"' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:32) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:366) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:229) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:117) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue '"incoming"' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:505) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:336) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:143) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:90) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:634) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:572) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

It is actually pretty difficult to determine if it is failing to connect to the queue after not noticing that it didn't create it or if it is failing in the initial creation.

There is no mention in any of the docker-specific documentation that implies that queues need to be explicitly created when running inside a docker container, and digging around inside the container, I find no config at all, which I believe implies that it should be allowed to create queues.

Not also that listing queues reveals an empty list, so this is not a problem with mismatched queue configuration from the queue I'm attempting to configure.

In an attempt to make everything completely explicit, I've got the following configuration class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableRabbit
public class Application {

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Autowired
  public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

  @Bean
  public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin() {
    return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
  }

  @Bean
  public Queue incomingQueue() {
    Queue queue = new Queue("${ep.service.baseline.listen.rabbitq.name}", true, false, false, null);
    return queue;
  }

  @Bean
  public Queue outboundQueue() {
    return new Queue("${ep.service.baseline.send.rabbitq.name}", true, false, false, null);
  }

  @Bean
  TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange("default-exchange", true, false);
  }

  @Bean
  Binding incomingBinding(@Qualifier("incomingQueue") Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queue.getName());
  }
  @Bean
  Binding outboundBinding(@Qualifier("outboundQueue") Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queue.getName());
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

and my listener is declared as follows:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${ep.service.baseline.listen.rabbitq.name}")
@Component
public class IncomingMessageProcessor {
  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IncomingMessageProcessor.class);

  @RabbitHandler
  public void process(@Payload String msg) {
    log.info("received message: {}", msg);
  }
}
```

And I receive the following errors:

```
2017-04-24 18:06:54.551 ERROR 38157 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.internalRabbitListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIllegalStateException: Fatal exception on listener startup
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at com.ep.service.baseline.Application.main(Application.java:65) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIllegalStateException: Fatal exception on listener startup
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doStart(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:846) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:552) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.java:279) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.start(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.java:235) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.QueuesNotAvailableException: Cannot prepare queue for listener. Either the queue doesn't exist or the broker will not allow us to use it.
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:548) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1382) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):["incoming"]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:621) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:520) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:105) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:101) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:123) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:992) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:50) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:955) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:600) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue '"incoming"' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:32) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:366) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:229) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:117) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue '"incoming"' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:505) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:336) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:143) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:90) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:634) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:572) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

The logs from rabbit look like this:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 24-Apr-2017::23:19:55 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.917.0> (172.17.0.1:42196 -> 172.17.0.3:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 24-Apr-2017::23:19:55 ===
Connection <0.917.0> (172.17.0.1:42196 -> 172.17.0.3:5672) has a client-provided name: rabbitConnectionFactory#0

=INFO REPORT==== 24-Apr-2017::23:19:55 ===
connection <0.917.0> (172.17.0.1:42196 -> 172.17.0.3:5672 - rabbitConnectionFactory#0): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'

=ERROR REPORT==== 24-Apr-2017::23:19:57 ===
Channel error on connection <0.917.0> (172.17.0.1:42196 -> 172.17.0.3:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'), channel 1:
operation queue.declare caused a channel exception not_found: no queue '"incoming"' in vhost '/'

=ERROR REPORT==== 24-Apr-2017::23:20:02 ===
Channel error on connection <0.917.0> (172.17.0.1:42196 -> 172.17.0.3:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'), channel 1:
operation queue.declare caused a channel exception not_found: no queue '"incoming"' in vhost '/'
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not related to docker, or the location of the broker at all.

It looks like you have some spurious `""` around your queue name...

> reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue `'"incoming"'` in vhost '/'

(Note the `"` within the `'`).

What is in this property `ep.service.baseline.listen.rabbitq.name` ?

Also, this won't work...

```
Queue queue = new Queue("${ep.service.baseline.listen.rabbitq.name}", true, false, false, null);
```

You can't use property placeholders there. That will create a queue named `${ep.service.baseline.listen.rabbitq.name}` - rabbit is very liberal with its naming rules.

You would need to use...

```
@Value("${ep.service.baseline.listen.rabbitq.name}")
private String queueName;

@Bean
public Queue incomingQueue() {
    Queue queue = new Queue(this.queueName, true, false, false, null);
    return queue;
}
```

DEBUG logging is always your friend; you will see all the queue declarations logged.

Comment: Thanks. The second issue was just an artifact of trying EVERYTHING to get it to work and wasn't part of my normal code, but you nailed it with your first thing - My properties file had quotes around the value, and then I wasn't seeing the problem in the error messages because quotes around values don't look odd in that context. You spotted the double-quoting in the log that I did not.

Comment: @Gary Russell :  Any idea about this   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47485314/how-to-implement-dead-letter-exchange-with-multiple-queue